# How do I send additional requests from a HttpMessageHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do something either extremely clever, or really stupid. That said, my problem is that during the call to the SendAsync() override in my HttpMessageHandler, I'm trying to fire an additional request to the same resource with a different method to check something, before I'm willing to let the original request through.

Here's a simplified version of my own HttpMessageHandler:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {
        // before actually doing what we're supposed to, I want to fire a GET request
        // to check something.
        var checkRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, request.RequestUri);
        var checkResponse = await base.SendAsync(checkRequest, cancellationToken);
        if (checkResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
            // Some more checking...
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Except, this won't work. My first `base.SendAsync` call fails with "500", and I have no clue why. I'm also interested to know if this is the way to move forward when having to do additional requests from a handler.

Comment: Its possible to achieve what you are trying to do (indeed web api batching support does something similar to this), but I would like to know more about your scenario. There are some thing that need to be taken care of if you plan to pump up the new requests with `HttpServer` like batching does, for example, Web API always makes sure to dispose any resources that were used as part of execution of a request. Since in this case you would be creating a new request and pumping up, you would need to handle this yourself.

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment...So, instead of all this, can you use `HttpClient` to make a full request...i agree that this is not as efficient as directly pumping up a request, but given the complexities that you need to take care, i would suggest using `HttpClient` instead...yeah, i know that in case of load balancing scenario this new request might not be coming to the same machine where it was created...if you can provide more details about your scenario, probably we can see if there are any alternative easy solutions.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a naive ETag handler, one that calculates an ETag as a hash of the content bytes, but in order to support the 'If-Match' check I need to obtain the current ETag. Therefore, I would like to submit a GET request to the same URL, calculate that ETag and compare, then return 412 or let the original request through.